# Trigger Code Insert and Update

Tags: apex, trigger

Need the trigger to fire on insert not just after update - how would I rewrite this trigger?  I need this trigger to fire off when it is created and when something gets changed.

Current trigger:

```
trigger LeadTriggerOwnerChange on Lead (after update) {
    LoanTeamTriggerHandler.changeOwnerMethodLead(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the after insert keywords:

```
trigger LeadTriggerOwnerChange on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    LoanTeamTriggerHandler.changeOwnerMethodLead(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Note that Trigger.oldMap will be null, so you may need to adjust your changeOwnerMethodLead method to account for this fact.

Comment: How would I adjust it to account for this? Trigger.oldMap will be null.  Would this be done on the Trigger or on the Apex Class?

Comment: @Jab.ottawa It'll depend on your code, but usually it looks something like `if(oldMap == null || oldMap.get(record.Id).field != newMap.get(record.Id).field)` Of course, the actual names of the variables will depend on your specific case. You can do this in the trigger handler.